# MySQLi Num Rows to check if row exist

Tags: php, mysqli

So used mysqli_num_rows to check if the ID exist. but now its not even loading up. But its crashing my script, not sure what i am missing, or if this just isn't written correctly.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. some times it takes fresh eyes to see some small errors and i have went over this over and over to find the issue.

```
$get_oc = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id from ap_oc where aff_id=$affiliate_id"));

if (mysqli_num_rows($get_oc) > 0) 
{
    $set_oc = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT commission from ap_oc where aff_id=$affiliate_id"));
    $comission = $set_oc['commission'];

    $get_tl_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT tl_id from ap_oc where aff_id=$affiliate_id"));
    $teamleaderid = $get_tl_id['tl_id'];

    $get_tl_oc = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id from ap_oc where aff_id=$teamleaderid"));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($get_tl_oc) > 0) {
            $set_tl_oc = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT commission from ap_oc where aff_id=$teamleaderid"));
            $t2_comission = $set_tl_oc['commission'];
        } 
}
```

Comment: You should always split the `mysqli_query` from the fetch assoc, if anything fails in the SQL you will always get a system error and not be able to handle this properly.  It will also help in debugging code as you can see what each stage is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished what i needed to do with this code

```
   $get_oc = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id from ap_oc where aff_id=$affiliate_id"));
    $count_oc = $get_oc['id'];
    if($count_oc==''){$count_oc = 0;}
     if ($count_oc > 0) 
        {
```

for anyone in the future that might have the same issues.